# Make nine-patch or make special-resolution images?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am aware that Android prefers nine-patch images as solution for all resolution/size screens. Now, I have to develop an app with approx 500 images and they are to be displayed on both mobile phones and tablets at perfect resolution.

What is the best way to do:
1. Turn all 500+ images into 9.png (bad side is time needed for this)
2. Turn all 500+ images into tablet's resolution and let all smaller screens use it (bad side is that I cannot predict all resolutions but make generic one)
3. Something else?

Basically my biggest concern are x-large screens and the option to make 2 versions is not allowed (although market supports multiple versions now).

What would be the optimum/best way? What would you do?

Comment: You could look into batching in Photoshop to save yourself massive amounts of time making the 9.png images

Comment: I did not understand what you have said :(. Did you suggest to use Photoshop to draw black 1px lines?

Comment: @everyone: One more thing. If I am to make 9.png from all those images, what would be the starting resolution? As we know, nine-patch documentation suggest we use the smallest-resolution image when creating 9.png.

Comment: why would you want to make ninepatch images? images should scale even without using ninepatches just fine?

Comment: @MrJre: My idea was to have them perfectly on all screens. Mobile displays are ok, but my concern was tablet's display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can have one folder for each screen-size, so you can put the pictures the size you want for each devices. The downside is the apk size gonna be really huge ! (which for me is really a problem on a mobile device).

So, for me, the best way is to do the 9.png

The question is probably "why do I need so many pictures?" If it's almost the same pic using several colors, maybe you can update the pic on the fly, just an idea.

Comment: As you said, making special image for each screen resolution is not an option. The app would have maybe more than 50 MB in size :). Regarding the other part of question, the images are the real images from everyday life and I cannot even store them on the remote server.

Comment: It's something like a wallpaper app' ? I asking myself if you can make an apk for each screen size and let the android market choose the better one for the phone. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html Look the last paragraph :)

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple versions are not achievable right now because of the deadline :(. The version 1.0 must be one APK only. This is the reason why I am not sure what is the best approach to this.

Comment: For me, the best way and easiest way to deal with your problem, is to make several release (which gonna be shown as just ONE app in the market) and it's better for the user experience (because the app gonna be really lighter !). For the deadline, i can't help '^^

Comment: You are right and I knew this :). But as I said, time does now allow us to make multiple versions at the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Turning all 500 images in to 9 patch will be hugely time consuming - it took me long enough just to do a couple!

I would have thought with 500 images there will be some common ground, are you able to modify the images so that you are using less, but the same one over? Are you able to make the images available for us to take a look at, perhaps that might help with other suggestions?

With the info you have provided, I am afraid to say the best and optimum way are different ways. The best way is the 9-patch, don't forget the screen size on phones also change, so it's not simply just two different images!

Comment: Sorry, NDA restricts me to post examples. But it's just regular images from the world around us. And no, I just cannot use less images.

Comment: so, how can you do 9.png with that ?

Comment: Yes I can if it is the best solution :)